# In useState of React, why does this not show the first console.log, rather than the second console.log here?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, state

Here, this is a really simple app.
I just expect it to log "Yes", not "No, array is something else" here.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

function Test(props) {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

  if (array === [1, 2, 3]) {
    console.log("Yes");
  } else {
    console.log("No, array is something else");
  }

  return <View></View>;
}

export default Test;
```

However, it actually logs the second one "No, array is something else".
Because the array of the state [1, 2, 3] was exactly equal to [1, 2, 3], I thought that would just show the first console.log("Yes")

I don't know what's going on here, or am I missing something?
It'd be nice if someone could give me some advice on it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: put you're condition in useEffect. it will most likely fix the issue

Comment: No, `useEffect` will not fix a basic misunderstanding of how equality works in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm guessing maybe it's because of the memory location with the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one also works

```
 if (array.toString() == [1, 2, 3].toString()) {
    console.log('Yes1');
  } else {
    console.log('No, array is something else');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `[1, 2, 3]===[1, 2, 3]` will return false even if two arrays are equal.

Try this,

```
 if (JSON.stringify(array).toString() == JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]).toString()) {
    console.log('Yes1');
  } else {
    console.log('No, array is something else');
  }
```

It will return true

Comment: why do you use .toString()? isn't it enough with the stringify?

Comment: Both will works

Comment: I have already told that approach below as well

Comment: I think the stringify method is better because it keeps the square brackets (`[]`), while the toString() method doesn't. But still i don't understand why using toString after stringify.